# Firebase Flutter Авторизация через Microsoft

Tags: firebase, flutter, auth

Можно ли во флаттере реализовать авторизацию через firebase и Microsoft? В документации Firebase сказано о разных соцсетях, но не про Microsoft, однако в методах авторизации в консоли Firebase он присутствует

Comment: уточняю, что меня интересуют android/ios платформы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На основе [документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/microsoft-oauth?authuser=0) можно сделать так (работает только для Flutter Web):

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

final OAuthProvider provider = OAuthProvider('microsoft.com');

// Необязательно: укажите дополнительные настраиваемые параметры OAuth, которые вы хотите отправить с запросом OAuth.
provider.setCustomParameters({
  'prompt': 'consent',
  'login_hint': 'user@firstadd.onmicrosoft.com'
});

// Необязательно: укажите дополнительные области OAuth 2.0 помимо базового профиля, которые вы хотите запросить у поставщика проверки подлинности.
provider.addScope('mail.read');
provider.addScope('calendars.read');

// Аутентифицирует клиента Firebase с помощью потока аутентификации OAuth на основе всплывающих окон.
UserCredential user = await auth.signInWithPopup(provider);

// Или аутентифицирует клиента Firebase с помощью потока перенаправления на всю страницу.
await auth.signInWithRedirect(provider);
UserCredential user = await auth.getRedirectResult();


// В дальнейшем вам нужно запомнить AuthCredential из UserCredential.credential и использовать его для аутентификации
UserCredential user = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

---

Для Flutter Android/iOS придется использовать плагин [firebase_auth_oauth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth):

```
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth().openSignInFlow(
  "microsoft.com", ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'your-tenent-id'});

// Или вы можете связать существующего вошедшего в систему пользователя 
User user = await FirebaseAuthOAuth()
          .linkExistingUserWithCredentials("microsoft.com", ["email openid"], {'tenant': 'your-tenent-id'});
```

Comment: Как я понял, это возможно только в веб версии. Решений для мобильных платформ нет?

Comment: @rulila52 это кросс-платформенное решение, документацию взял за основу.

Comment: Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: signInWithPopup() is only supported on web based platforms
 Unhandled Exception: UnimplementedError: signInWithRedirect() is only supported on web based platforms

Comment: @rulila52 и правда, не заметил, тогда придётся использовать [firebase_auth_oauth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth_oauth)

Comment: напишите это как ответ, я помечу его решением

Comment: @rulila52 отредактировал ответ